# Error when making package.json using 'npm init' command

Tags: node.js, json, npm

When running `npm init` to create a `package.json` file the following error occurs:

> ```
> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
> 1 verbose cli [
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
> 1 verbose cli   'init'
> 1 verbose cli ]
> 2 info using npm@6.12.0
> 3 info using node@v12.13.0
> 4 silly package data {
> 4 silly package data   name: 'mangabackend',
> 4 silly package data   version: '1.0.0',
> 4 silly package data   description: '',
> 4 silly package data   main: 'index.js',
> 4 silly package data   scripts: { test: 'echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1' },
> 4 silly package data   author: 'vansh',
> 4 silly package data   license: 'ISC'
> 4 silly package data }
> 5 info init written successfully
> 6 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program 
> Files\nodejs\mangabackend\MangaBackEnd\package.json'
> 7 verbose cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs\mangabackend\angaBackEnd
> 8 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
> 9 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
> Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "init"
> 10 verbose node v12.13.0
> 11 verbose npm  v6.12.0
> 12 error code EPERM
> 13 error syscall open
> 14 error path C:\Program Files\nodejs\mangabackend\MangaBackEnd\package.json
> 15 error errno -4048
> 16 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program
>  Files\nodejs\mangabackend\MangaBackEnd\package.json'
> 16 error  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program 
> Files\nodejs\mangabackend\MangaBackEnd\package.json'] {
> 16 error   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\\Program 
> Files\\nodejs\\mangabackend\\MangaBackEnd\\package.json'"
> 16 error   errno: -4048,
> 16 error   code: 'EPERM',
> 16 error   syscall: 'open',
> 16 error   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\mangabackend\\MangaBackEnd\\package.json'
> 16 error }
> 17 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> 17 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
> 17 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
> 17 error
> 17 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> 17 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> 17 error the command again as root/Administrator.
> 18 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
> ```

I'm a noob and I don't know what to do. Please help me.

I don't what these errors mean I only wanted to create a `package.json`.

Comment: Open cmd with admin rights and install :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't make package .js npm and get errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435961/i-cant-make-package-js-npm-and-get-errors)

Answer (score 0):

This is a **`permission`** issue, Please give `complete permissions` to

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program 
>   Files\nodejs\mangabackend\MangaBackEnd\package.json'

This error meant that you are unable to create **`package.json`** file inside `MangaBackEnd folder`

**`C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\mangabackend\MangaBackEnd`**

You can check [this link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/give-permissions-to-files-and-folders-in-windows/78ee562c-a21f-4a32-8691-73aac1415373) and [this link](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/) on how to give permissions in `windows`

**(Or)**

You can open **command prompt** with **`Administrator`** and can also do it.